# Add column value only if not already set

Tags: hbase

I use `hbase-client` to push data to a HBase table.

For this, I create a `Put` object like in the following.

```scala
val data = new Put(/*key as Bytes*/)
put.addColumn(family,identifier,value)
table.put(data)
```

What could I do if I wanted to implement one of the clauses - logically identical - : "do not put if the value for my key/family/qualifier has already a value" or "copy value for my key/family/identifier if it has already a value"?

Do I have to proceed to a `Get` beforehand? Or does another method exist?

Comment: Hello wipman , just to clarify, If you insert cf1:c1 first and then call cf2:c2 then the row will have c1 and c2 with values. 
If you put cf1:c1 the second time , a new version will be inserted , you may either need to Get or get a prior version to get the record before

Comment: The thing is my colleagues use a tool that cannot claim former versions of a `Row` and can only get the last version. That is the reason why I am asking such a strange question.